# What causes '_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed'?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, conda

I've created a chat GUI. The problem is, outside pycharm it's not working properly. By "not working properly" I mean the font it displays is not the one of my choice. Also the size of that font and display box isn't the one I've chosen. The error displayed in the program using this GUI is the one in the title. I think conda may be responsible for this, but I'm not sure. Am I right about this, or is this something else? And also how can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("430x720")
window.config(bg="#2b2929")

message_box = tkinter.Text(window, height=32, state="disabled") 
message_box.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, padx=15,pady=5, fill=tkinter.Y)
message_box.config(bg="#595959", fg="#ffffff", font=("Impact", 12))

input_user = tkinter.StringVar()
text_box = tkinter.Text(window, height=5)
text_box.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM,  padx=15, pady=8)
text_box.config(bg="#595959", fg="#ffffff", font=("Impact", 12))


def send_message(event):
    input_get = text_box.get('1.0', tkinter.END)
    if input_get.isspace():
        input_user.set('')
        text_box.delete('1.0', tkinter.END)
        return "break"

    message_box.configure(state='normal')
    message_box.insert(tkinter.INSERT, input_get)
    message_box.see("end")
    message_box.configure(state='disabled')
    input_user.set('')
    text_box.delete('1.0', tkinter.END)
    return "break"


text_box.bind("<Return>", send_message)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code won't run as is -- there is an indentation issue as well as an attempt to call `return` outside of a function. I don't think it's possible for this code to produce the error you say it does even when the indentation issues are fixed.

Comment: Sorry, it was pasted here incorrectly. The original version is just like the one below, but it still doesn't work the way it should outside PyCharm.

Comment: Your code works as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works, I've only indent last rows.

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("430x720")
window.config(bg="#2b2929")

message_box = tkinter.Text(window, height=32, state="disabled") 
message_box.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, padx=15,pady=5, fill=tkinter.Y)
message_box.config(bg="#595959", fg="#ffffff", font=("Impact", 12))

input_user = tkinter.StringVar()
text_box = tkinter.Text(window, height=5)
text_box.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM,  padx=15, pady=8)
text_box.config(bg="#595959", fg="#ffffff", font=("Impact", 12))


def send_message(event):
    input_get = text_box.get('1.0', tkinter.END)
    if input_get.isspace():
        input_user.set('')
        text_box.delete('1.0', tkinter.END)
        return "break"

    message_box.configure(state='normal')
    message_box.insert(tkinter.INSERT, input_get)
    message_box.see("end")
    message_box.configure(state='disabled')
    input_user.set('')
    text_box.delete('1.0', tkinter.END)
    return "break"


text_box.bind("<Return>", send_message)
window.mainloop()
```

[image]